# Pandas Series name not showing up as part of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am concatenating a Series onto a dataframe, but the column name (Series name) is not showing up on the new dataframe.

Instead, the column has the name '0' in the final dataframe, but while it is being made in the apply_join method, the name does show up.

Why is the Series name not being seen in the dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

tibble3_csv = """country,year,cases,population
Afghanistan,1999,745,19987071
Afghanistan,2000,2666,20595360"""
with StringIO(tibble3_csv) as fp:
    tibble3 = pd.read_csv(fp)

 def str_join_elements(x, sep=""):
    assert type(sep) is str
    return sep.join((str(xi) for xi in x))

 def unite(df, cols, new_var, combine=str_join_elements):
    def apply_join(x, combine):
         joinstr = combine(x)
         ser = pd.Series(joinstr, name=new_var)
         print(ser.name)
        return ser

     fixed_vars = df.columns.difference(cols)
     tibble = df[fixed_vars].copy()
     tibble_extra = df[cols].apply(apply_join, combine=combine, axis=1)

     return pd.concat([tibble, tibble_extra], axis=1) 

 tab = unite(tibble3, ['cases', 'population'], 'rate', combine=lambda x: str_join_elements(x, "/"))
 print(tab)
```

Result:

```
rate
rate
       country  year                  0
 0  Afghanistan  1999       745/19987071
1  Afghanistan  2000      2666/20595360
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to concatenate an unknown number of columns, you can use `apply` with `str.join`:

```
def foo(df, columns, col_name, sep=''):
    s = df[columns].apply(lambda x: sep.join(map(str, x)), 1)
    s.name = col_name
    return pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference(columns)], s], axis=1)

df
       country  year  cases  population
0  Afghanistan  1999    745    19987071
1  Afghanistan  2000   2666    20595360

df2 = foo(df, ['cases', 'population'], 'rate', '/')
df2
       country  year           rate
0  Afghanistan  1999   745/19987071
1  Afghanistan  2000  2666/20595360
```

---

If it's always going to be two columns, you can use `str.cat`, it's much faster.

```
def foo2(df, c1, c2, c3, sep=''):
    s1, s2 = df[c1].astype(str), df[c2].astype(str)
    s3 = s1.str.cat(s2, sep=sep)
    s3.name = c3
    return pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference([c1, c2])], s3], axis=1)

df2 = foo2(df, 'cases', 'population', 'rate', '/')
df2
       country  year           rate
0  Afghanistan  1999   745/19987071
1  Afghanistan  2000  2666/20595360
```

Comment: I like your simple solution. This is an assignment however, and the method signature of "foo/unite" includes a function being passed, "combine" in this case.

Comment: @cumin Well, just use `tibble_extra.name = 'rate'` before calling `pd.concat`. :/

Comment: @cumin The reason your original dataframe does not have the column named is because the result of `tibble_extra` does not have a name. You need to assign one to it. This name will become part of the output df later.

Comment: It seems pretty clunky that I have to add that in ` tibble_extra.columns =[new_var]`, but it looks like I do. That works

Answer (score 0):

You can also just try to rename column using

```
>>> tab = tab.rename(columns = {0:'cases/population'})
>>> tab
       country  year cases/population
0  Afghanistan  1999     745/19987071
1  Afghanistan  2000    2666/20595360
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work. But why doesn't the name of the column ("rate") show up in the df when it does show up when the Series is being made at `print(ser.name)`?